# Writing a singly linked list and running test code on it

Tags: java, collections, singly-linked-list

So we've got this assignment where we're supposed to write a singly linked list. I've done that part but the teacher wants us to add a method names isHealthy() that tests some conditions. I'm having trouble implementing code that tests one of the conditions.

Here is the class and constructor and the isHealthy method:

```
/**
 * A singly linked list.
 * 
 */
public class LinkedList<T> { 
private ListElement<T> first;   // First element in list.
private ListElement<T> last;    // Last element in list.
private int size;               // Number of elements in list.

/**
 * A list element.
 */
private static class ListElement<T> {
    public T data;
    public ListElement<T> next;

    public ListElement(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an empty list.
 */
public LinkedList() {
    // TODO
    first = null;
    last = null;
    size = 0;
}

/**
 * This TEST METHOD returns true if the following invariants hold:
 * <ul>
 *   <li> size equals the number of list elements, </li>
 *       *****Rest of the conditions omitted*****
 * </ul>
 */
public boolean isHealthy() {
    // TODO
    boolean var = false;
    int counter;
    if(first == null && last == null) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    else {
        for(T elements : ) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if(counter == size) {
        var = true;
    }
  return var;
}
******Rest of code omitted******
```

So basically I need to prove that the size field equals the number of list elements. As you can see I'm attempting to do this by having a local variable named **counter** that is set to 0 if the list has no elements.

If there are elements then my plan was to iterate through the list and add a value to the **counter** variable everytime a new element was found. Then I will check if **counter** holds the same value as size and if it does then it's correct..

The problem I have is how am I supposed to iterate through the list when this class is the List? That is what am I supposed to write here:

```
 for(T elements : **here** )
```

Is it possible to iterate through a list in the class of the list?

Comment: Have the class that creates the linked list also have the `isHealthy()` method. Then you can call `isHealthy()` on your fully created list. You can iterate through in the class you have now by using the `next` variable in your list, but the counter will not match up to the total count if you are calling `isHealthy()` from one of the middle elements in the list

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isHealthy(){

    int counter = 0;
    ListElement<T> node = first;
    while(node.next != null){
        counter++;
        node = node.next;
    }

     // this checks if the if statement fails 
     // or not and returns the result(true/false)
    return if (counter == size);
}
```

You just have to check if the next element exists.

Comment: `return counter == size;` is more succinct, and IMO just as readable.

Comment: @BrianS totally agree, i actually completely missed it. It might be less readable for the OP, seems a bit new to programming. But good suggestion ill add it and a little note what it does.

Comment: Thx for the reply.. The problem I'm getting with this is that when you have no elements then:

first == null. Hence node == null.

In the while loop when executing isHealthy without any elements the node.next statement brings upp the 

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

error

Comment: @user3043462 Alot of link lists have the "head" node(first) as a placeholder or an initial empty node just to account for a problem like this. However, you can just add a conditional before, `if(first == null) ->if(size == 0)return true; else return false;` since there is no elements you need to return zero.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have **here** put your list ot collection of (Iterable) elements. 
I understand you have more elements, not only "first" and "last", so put there your list of ListElement.
BTW, don't know what JVM you youse but calling the class LinkedList it doesn't compile. Is this inner class?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the for each loop you need to implement the [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface. Since your class definition doesn't allow that I think the best solution if iterating using the next variable, something like:

```
it = first;
while(it != last){
  it = it.next;
  counter++;
}
```

You can also use a more elegant recursive method to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a question isn't it better to have: "while(it != null)" ?

Because having "it != last" makes it stop the counter one time before the last element? If i have "it != null" then when we reach the last element it.next points to null and the while loop stops.